# Ubuntu 18 to 22

Tags: server, 18.04, 22.04

I'm trying to upgrade server boxes from 18 to 22 via cli. I know it's best to start fresh and was able to on all but 3 boxes. I have to manually update these. I've seen a lot of questions/answers that asks to go to LTS but it's bad to go from 18 to 22 right? Figured doing a `do-release-upgrade` wasn't smart.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, but the normal `do-release-upgrade` path is 18.04 → 20.04 → 22.04.

Comment: Actually... that's what I needed to know @FedKad I didn't want to jump from 18 to 22 in one jump. THANKS!!!

Comment: Please, run `do-release-upgrade -c` first and check its output.

Comment: Ahhh it says "New release 20.04.6 LTS is available"

Comment: The answer pretty much did. As in no. :) I definitely did NOT want to go from 18 straight to 22.

Comment: Be aware, the upgrade process from 18 to 20 differs from 18.04 to 20.04 as they are different systems. The *year* products (Ubuntu Core 18, Ubuntu Core 20) are *snap* only thus user-packages are identical for both systems and do not need to change. The *year.month* systems (Ubuntu 18.04 & Ubuntu 20.04) use *deb* packages which are packaged for each release, thus all *deb* packages upgrade during the upgrade, though the *snap* packages will not upgrade. You mix *year* and *year.month* details - which are different Ubuntu products (18 & 18.04 are different)

Comment: That is VERY good information to be aware of @guiverc. Thank you for that!!